# saods9 package require base64

Tags: command-line, 20.04

i have been running ds9 on Ubuntu, but got some massage error.

Error in startup script: can't find package base64
while executing
"package require base64"
(file "/usr/share/saods9/library/ds9.tcl" line 216)

Can you help me to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/lheasoft/issues.html (formatting my own):

> **Ubuntu ds9 & HEASoft:**
>
> After initializing HEASoft on Ubuntu Linux, the `ds9` GUI (if
> installed) may fail to start up (mentioning `can't find package xml`,
> `can't find package uri 1.1`, or `package require base64`). This
> results from incompatibilities between the Tcl/Tk included with
> HEASoft and the Ubuntu system libraries. Until a more elegant solution
> can be devised, we recommend that users try one of the following
> options, depending on the file type of your `ds9` (shell script or
> compiled executable - check the output from `` file `which ds9` ``  to
> determine which it is):
>
> 1. If `ds9` is the shell script version, edit it to change the line
>
>    ```
>    exec wish8.6 -f ${DS9_HOME-/usr/share/saods9}/library/ds9.tcl $*
>    ```
>
>    to
>
>    ```
>    exec /usr/bin/env -u LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/bin/wish8.6 -f ${DS9_HOME-/usr/share/saods9}/library/ds9.tcl $*
>    ```
>
> or
>
> 2. If `ds9` is the compiled executable version, create a new file
>    `$HEADAS/bin/ds9` containing the following lines:
>
>    ```
>    #!/bin/sh
>    exec /usr/bin/env -u LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/bin/ds9 "$@"
>    ```
>
>    (Note this assumes that `which ds9` = `/usr/bin/ds9`)
>
>    To make the new script executable, run the following command:
>
>    ```
>    $ chmod +x $HEADAS/bin/ds9
>    ```
>
>    Then, as long as `$HEADAS/bin` is ahead of `/usr/bin` in your
>    `PATH`, you should now be able to successfully run `ds9` from the
>    command line:
>
>    ```
>    $ rehash
>    $ ds9
>    ```